# Motherboard will fully reboot, except with reset/shutdown button

Tags: motherboard, reboot

I have a intel d525mw motherboard, on which I have ubuntu server.

When I go to reboot my machine(sudo reboot), it goes to the restart prompt and then just hangs there.
I have also noticed this when I had freebsd on it.

It kills everything and drops to a shell view where the final line reads something like "[timestamp] restarting now" and then it just sits there and I manually have to reboot it.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: You should rewrite your question.. exactly how you reboot your machine when you say "when I go to reboot my machine"

Comment: i use "sudo reboot"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the same problem. Attach an (unpowered) monitor to it and it will reboot.

This seems to be a flaw in the BIOS that more people are reporting about.

Comment: same motherboard? I hope they come out with a BIOS fix for that.. I need to be able to remotely reboot this machine

Answer (score 1):

There are some suggestions in this [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=767799) thread.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me:

In the `/etc/default/grub` file, add `reboot=bios` to the below line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=bios"
```

Now rebooting, halting and shutting down works properly.

Remember to run the following after the change is saved:

```
sudo update-grub
```